# How to run jquery on Wix website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velo

I know that the Wix doesn't support Jquery yet so the only option I have is to run it in their HTML editor. So I got the HTML, Jquery and CSS code running perfectly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aeyqpL8u/12/) on jsfiddle.

But when I try to run all these codes in their **Edit code** window, Jquery doesn't work and play/pause audio players loses its transition.

Here's what I tried to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.control').on('mousedown', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('pause play');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    $('.control').toggleClass('pause play');
  }
});

</script>

<div class="control play trigger-audio">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor" volume="1.0"></audio>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="control play trigger-audio">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925" volume="1.0"></audio>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.control {
    border: 2.0px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 28px;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control,
.control .left,
.control .right,
.control:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: border 0.4s, width 0.4s, height 0.4s, margin 0.4s;
    transition-tiomig-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.control:before {
    content: "";
    height: 112px;
}

.control.pause .left,
.control.pause .right {
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 36.96px solid #333;
    border-top: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    height: 96.992px;
}

.control.pause .left {
    border-right: 22.4px solid transparent;
}

.control.play .left {
    margin-left: 18.66666667px;
    border-left: 48.496px solid #333;
    border-top: 28px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    height: 56px;
}

.control.play .right {
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 48.496px solid #333;
    border-top: 28px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
}

.control:hover {
    border-color: #000;
}

.control:hover .left,
.control:hover .right {
    border-left-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm a beginner so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think what you need to understand is that Wix Code is essentially its own jQuery. Wix Code is a javascript API into Wix's own DOM extrapolation framework and does similar things to jQuery.

Elements are created in the Wix Editor and then you interact with them using the Wix DOM using the $w() scope selector and element IDs.

To use raw HTML like this you would need to add an iframe to your Wix Page and then run your code, sandboxed, in the iframe. Check out this article for more information:

- https://support.wix.com/en/article/guidelines-and-limitations-of-the-html-code-and-embed-a-site-elements

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i just saw it :)

The format of your code is wrong. You have your html layout in the `head` section instead of the `body`. Another issue is that you have your functional script before the html layout is rendered so it probably wont' work. (jsfiddle adds the javascript section on the bottom of the `body` by default)

Check out this approach:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
.control {
border: 2.0px solid #333;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 20px;
padding: 28px;
width: 112px;
height: 112px;
font-size: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}

.control,
.control .left,
.control .right,
.control:before {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
transition: border 0.4s, width 0.4s, height 0.4s, margin 0.4s;
transition-tiomig-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.control:before {
content: "";
height: 112px;
}

.control.pause .left,
.control.pause .right {
margin: 0;
border-left: 36.96px solid #333;
border-top: 0 solid transparent;
border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
height: 96.992px;
}

.control.pause .left {
border-right: 22.4px solid transparent;
}

.control.play .left {
margin-left: 18.66666667px;
border-left: 48.496px solid #333;
border-top: 28px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
border-right: 0px solid transparent;
height: 56px;
}

.control.play .right {
margin: 0;
border-left: 48.496px solid #333;
border-top: 28px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
height: 0px;
}

.control:hover {
border-color: #000;
}

.control:hover .left,
.control:hover .right {
border-left-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="control play trigger-audio">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor" volume="1.0"></audio>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="control play trigger-audio">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925" volume="1.0"></audio>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>

<script>
$('.control').on('mousedown', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('pause play');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
$('.control').toggleClass('pause play');
  }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**You have to use the Custom code feature of Wix. (it's not for free plan)** 

 1. Go to Wix dashboard => Settings => Custom Code => Add Custom Code. 
 2. Add this code to the head part of your site and select the settings
    "All Pages" so that it runs for all pages.

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

 3. Add this code to the <body> of your site

    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
      // Your jQuery code here });
    </script>
```

Reference: https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/can-you-use-jquery-in-wix/